# How to achieve Large Type like Address Book?

Tags: cocoa, macos

Within Address Book you can click on a contact's phone number label and select the option 'Large Type' which displays the phone number in large text in what appears to be an HUD window. I saw one other application use this but cannot figure out how to achieve this.

What really interests me is

1. how they have the titlebar-less window.
2. the text has a drop shadow
3. the font size shrinks to fit if it's really long.

The only way I was thinking of doing this is creating a regular HUD window, and manually coding something that determines the size of font to show depending on how many characters.

Comment: That's pretty much it - draw it yourself.  If you have any specific questions, ask them...

Comment: I see. I guess I'll continue doing it this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quicksilver for this. There's an old article talking about how to use Quicksilver for timed reminders that uses the Large Type feature.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to show some text with a large font you could do it inside your browser with [large-type.com](http://large-type.com/):

```
$ open http://large-type.com/#YourText
```